# Why is my C# (Mono) application using low CPU?

Tags: c#, mono, cpu-usage

I have a (white-hat) password cracking tool that is constantly incrementing a password string and then hashing it to compare it with the supplied hash (that I want to crack). However, the program is only using 14% of CPU.

The application has two threads, only one of which should be resource intensive. My machine has 4 cores with hyper-threading (8 virtual cores). Not even one core has CPU usage above 25% though. According to the resource monitor, the work appears to be spread around (each core is averaging around 12%).

Is there a way to make it use more CPU and hopefully run faster or does it not work that way?

Comment: How many processors/core does your machine have? Is your application single-threaded? Have you tried changing the process priority?

Comment: The application has two threads, only one of which should be resource intensive. My machine has 4 cores with hyper-threading (8 virtual cores). Not even one core has high CPU usage though, according to the resource monitor, the work appears to be spread around (each core is averaging around 12%).

Comment: 8 * 12 = 96 (or 8 x 12.5 = 100). Since the meat of your app is single-threaded, it can only run on a single core at once. It's jumping from core to core as per normal process scheduling rules. As it uses each core, it uses 100% of that core for the duration it's on that core. But it's only on each core 1/8 of the time.

Comment: Is this a GPU cracker, because it might be doing all the hashing on the GPU and just the comparisons on the CPU?

Comment: This is a good example of an *embarrassingly parallel* problem; consider using the Task Parallel Library. It is specifically designed to farm work out to different processors.

Comment: That makes sense @MichaelGunter, if you add that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Idrumm, No lol. That would be fuuny.

Comment: @Idrumm, If I made a GPU cracker and then asked why the CPU usage is low. The GPU is doing the work.

Comment: Answer added. Mark away! :)

Comment: @Razick you didn't mention you made it (having provided very few details in your question-   "I have a (white-hat) password cracking tool"), only that it's only using 25% of the CPU.  It's a reasonable leap to go from there to 'the CPU is waiting for something', and then to hypothesise the possibilty that this unexplained password cracker is-GPU bound.

Comment: @ldrumm I meant no offense. I meant it would be stupid OF ME to ask why CPU usage is low when the GPU is doing the work. I agree, it was a reasonable possibility from your perspective.

Comment: none taken:) I just wanted to clarify my interpretation.  All done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 * 12 = 96 (or 8 x 12.5 = 100). Since the meat of your app is single-threaded, it can only run on a single core at once. It's jumping from core to core as per normal process scheduling rules. As it uses each core, it uses 100% of that core for the duration it's on that core. But it's only on each core 1/8 of the time.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to accept Aydin Adn's instead because I think it will better help future readers. Thank you though, it helped me understand.

Comment: You can accept both as answers, y'know. Mine did more directly answer your question.

Comment: I tried, it wouldn't let me. Yeah, but I think most people who might search this will not understand multi-threading.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way would obviously be to multi-thread it. Since most modern CPUs have multiple cores, if you use a single thread, you can only make use of one core at a time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

The above is a tutorial for multithreading.

As for a tactic, since you seem to be brute-forcing the password, you can have multiple 'string incrementing' happening starting at a different initial string.

Comment: The strange thing is that not even one core is over 25%.

Comment: You said you;re 'incrementing a string'. You ARE using a StringBuilder right? If you're using a string you're wasting time trashing the memory

Comment: Yes, I am using a string builder.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is what's called MultiThreading, at the moment your application is running on a single thread, if you want it to run on more you need to learn how to split the task in question in to equal chunks.

Another problem you will be facing is thread safety issues because your threads will be sharing the same resources. To avoid the issues that arrive with it you will need to lock the data that you are trying to access which will block other threads from accessing the resource until a thread is done with it.

How to use threads

```
var thread = new Thread(()=> RunMethod());
thread.Start();
```

How to lock data:

```
private static readonly Object lock = new Object();
private void RunMethod()
{
    Lock(lock)
    {
        // Access or modify shared resource
    }
}
```